# How to get html source of current website with filled input values

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want clone current state of website with all filled inputs values.

I was tried this `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);` but this is not set input values.

Comment: I think using jQuery will make it simple enough: basically a $("input").val() will do the job (you may need to handle checkboxes with a separate selector, just like Selects (combo-boxes)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clone() function in jQuery that will do the trick:

```
$("#container").clone().appendTo("#cloneTo");
```

With this cloned object you update all value-attributes of the input fields in the DOM:

```
$("#cloneTo input:text").each(function () {
     $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

Do the same with all other DOM elements, where you need the values.

After that you can print the resulting HTML with:

```
alert($("#cloneTo")[0].outerHTML);
```

See working example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daq0n0o8/2/

Hope that helps :)

---

**Based on the question in the comments from user "really", I create a special step by step "How to":**

1. Open your page in chrome: http://olx.pl/nowe-ogloszenie
2. Hit F12, so the Chrome Console is visible ([Documentation from google](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwiv1-jaibPHAhWBDiwKHallAEM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.chrome.com%2Fdevtools%2Fdocs%2Fconsole&ei=gmDTVa-OCoGdsAGpy4GYBA&usg=AFQjCNHxGDhMtf3k-GNV6_EPS2GCosxanQ&sig2=iPJo3aPV1gwxV_uAzhs-4g)) Maybe you have to click the ">_" button in the upper right to let the console come up.
3. Edit one input field on your homepage, so you can see later it is copied.
4. Paste following code behind the prompt ">"

Paste first part and hit ENTER:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Paste second part and hit ENTER:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'cloneTo';
document.body.appendChild(div);
$("#innerLayout").clone().appendTo("#cloneTo");
$("#cloneTo input:text").each(function () {
     $(this).attr("value", $(this).val());
});
```

5. Your page is cloned at the bottom. You can alert the output by:

Paste and hit ENTER:

```
alert($("#cloneTo")[0].outerHTML);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I need get source with all values.

Comment: What values you are missing? in my example the values from the input fields are copied.

Comment: This in c#  webBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml; give me back html source.  When i paste in html file and open in firefox i have full cloned website with filled inputs. I need it in javascript. I was tried to use document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].outerHTML in javascript but this is not clone my text in inputs fields.

Comment: Rigth, outerHTML does not give you the input field values for example, but if you try the jQuery function clone() it does! Just click on the button in my fiddle and you see how it appends all DOM elements include the current value of the input field to the div element. So you could do whatever you want with this cloned object.

Comment: So how can i implement this function to for e.g alert cloned document source?

Comment: ok, now I understand ;) I updated the answer. Please vote as the solution if it helps ;)

Comment: This is good why i have only one input but i have website like this http://i.imgur.com/qruNE6d.png . With random inputs and listbox. I need take html "screenshot" :(

Comment: Here you can see the alert output of HTML and values: http://jsfiddle.net/daq0n0o8/2/. It is that what you need?

Comment: I don't know how to use your solution on this page http://olx.pl/nowe-ogloszenie/ . I want get source with all inputs values and selected options.

Comment: @really: I did enhance the answer with a step by step guide

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("input[type=text]").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("value",$(this).val());
    });
    $("input[type=hidden]").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("value",$(this).val());
    });
    $("textarea").each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).val());
    });
    $("input[type=radio]").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("checked")=="checked")
            $(this).attr("checked","checked");
        else
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("checked")=="checked")
            $(this).attr("checked","checked");
        else
            $(this).removeAttr("checked");
    });
    $("select option").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("selected")=="selected")
            $(this).attr("selected","true");
        else
            $(this).removeAttr("selected");
    });
    $("#source").html();
```